# Fast CMS for Community website

Tags: php, cms, framework, multi-user

I'm looking for a CMS which is

- fast and lightweight (probably enriched with ajax)
- easy to code, extend and maintain (maybe built on a framework such as Laravel). I am a pure php programmer but would like to learn a good framework which make things easier

some functionalities are (I want it for university associations)

- Multi user, multi communities support (like different blogs on subdomains)
- Ability to join comunities, post on each of them
- Asking questions, posting contents, scoring answers (maybe something similar StackOverFlow)
- As my language is Persian, easy to internationalize

I myself found PyroCMS, however its based on CodeIgnitor while I wish it based on Laravel.
PongoCMS is based on Laravel but I'm afraid its not as powerful as Pyro

Do popular CMSs like Joomla or Wordpress have significant advantages which I may lose using a CMS based on a framework?

Actually what are top and promising nowadays CMSs?

Comment: What do you exactly mean with a *fast and lightweight* CMS?

Comment: for example a website like StackOverFlow, Less page refreshes, do small jobs (for example editing a comment) inline and fast, and load the pages also fast, using cache....

Comment: Wiki has a good list of frameworks, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_content_management_frameworks

Comment: Can you update your request and include what types of CMS functionality you are looking for as well as any limitations, technical or otherwise?

Comment: @James I did some modifications

Answer (score 2):

To answer this part of your question:

> Do popular CMSs like Joomla or Wordpress have significant advantages which I may lose using a CMS based on a framework?

Wordpress is very popular CMS, so it's very easy to find a support when you have a problem. You can propably find someone who know it in your acquaintances. Wordpress is regulary updated, and innovations are often added.

Because it's very popular, a large amount of plugins exist and are regulary updated. For instance I've already tried the antispam one's (Askimet implementation for Wp), and it is very powerful.

Here the advantage I see for popular CMS, but if you like low level CMS, the Wordpress core is easily accessible, and well documented (if I compare with my very quick Jomla experience). This backend part could be considered a framework. And then you can implement by your self the functionnality you need (Update the content with Ajax, custom caching...) while using powerful Wp functionnality (hooks, ORM, feeding already available, ...)

Comment: Wordpress is great for communities too. Most themes cater extremely well to mobile, making it great for people who are socializing before they sleep. Blog is easily integrated. There are plenty of plugins for things like galleries and forums too.

Answer (score 1):

> (I want it for university associations)

You will need to do a fair bit of customizing to get the functionality you want from the standard CMSs, I believe, although that would of course be possible.

However, I think [Elgg](http://www.elgg.org/) would be able to give you most of the functionality you want. It is a "social networking engine", aimed in particular at "businesses, schools, universities...". [Athabasca University](https://landing.athabascau.ca/) is an example of an Elgg-powered site.

- [image: Note] fast and lightweight (probably enriched with ajax) | **hard to say!**
- [image: Yes] easy to code, extend and maintain.... I am a pure php programmer... | **see [requirements](http://www.elgg.org/requirements.php) and [documentation](http://docs.elgg.org/wiki/Main_Page)**

---

- [image: Yes]  Multi user, multi communities support (like different blogs on subdomains)
- [image: Yes]  Ability to join comunities, post on each of them
- [image: Yes] / [image: Note] Asking questions, posting contents, scoring answers (maybe something similar StackOverFlow) | **yes, available as 3rd party plugins; some look like they need some patching**
- [image: Note] As my language is Persian, easy to internationalize | **available for [1.7](http://community.elgg.org/plugins/512692/1.1/persian-farsi-translation-17-171) (current version 1.8.19)**

---

I haven't used Elgg "in anger", although I did play with a test install a few years ago. It has been around a long time, has a good user base, and a fairly distinctive feature set that matches your use case. It's worth considering, I would think.

Comment: thank you for your answer, I checked it, its very good for associations. easy to learn, and fast enough.

Answer (score -1):

Try this one, if you know or want to know angularjs, It's "enriched with ajax" :)

it doesn't have all functionality you require, but will give you good starting point.

https://github.com/DimitriMikadze/laravel-angular-cms

Comment: Please detail what requirements are covered and which ones are not, thanks!

Comment: This are covered. its not big CMS like drupal, joomla ... its very optimized and good starting point. 1) fast and lightweight (probably enriched with ajax) 2) easy to code, extend and maintain... 3) Multi user, multi communities support

Comment: Please put this information inside your answer, thanks!